# Convert HDF5 string into Matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab, hdf5

I have a HDF5 file that I've read into Matlab:

```
>> people_list = hdf5read('test_set.h5', 'people_list')

    hdf5.h5string: 52-by-1
```

How do I convert this structure into a Matlab cell array, similar to:

```
>> {'Bob', 'Yang', 'Carol'}

ans = 

    'Bob'    'Yang'    'Carol'
```

I can view the string of each individual unit, for example:

```
>> people_list(1).Data

ans =

Bob
```

So I can iterate through it and assign each value to a cell:

```
post = cell(1, size(people_list,1));
for p_i = 1:size(people_list,1)
    post(p_i) = {people_list(p_i).Data};
end
```

But is there a way to do it without a for-loop?

Comment: `post{p_i}` I assume? Also, whats wrong with the for loop?

Comment: @AnderBiguri suprisingly `post(p_i)` works, but `post{p_i}` is probably more correct and explicit. The for-loop itself feels a bit silly, like there should be some group of functions for this type of thing that might be useful to know about.